# Infinite loop php redirect based on cookie

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I'm currenting busy coding a registration page. The page has three steps and every step has its own cookie value. What I'd like to do is checking for the cookies value and transfer the user to the correct page upon visiting the website

Example:
if the value of $_COOKIE['step'] is 'step_two' it should redirect to: www.domain.com/register.php?step=your_details. If the cookie's not set, it should not redirect and stay on the register.php page.

The redirecting is working 'fine', but it gets into an infinite loop. I really cant think clear anymore as I've been awake for almost 24h now. Therefor I would appreciate it if anyone could push me into the right directions.

**Piece of code:**

```
$cookie_value = 'step_2';
setcookie("step",$cookie_value, time()+3600*24);

$cookie_not_set = true;
$cookie_step_two = false;

if (isset($_COOKIE['step'])) {
    if ($_COOKIE['step'] == 'step_2') {
        $cookie_not_set = false;
        $cookie_step_two = true;
        header('Location: ?step=your_details');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    $cookie_not_set = true;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you've been up for 24 hours, I really suggest taking a nap.  It will help your code, and is probably the best investment in your time at the moment.

Comment: 1) Your `header` call is invalid as your missing a closing quote `'`   2). You will constantly be in a redirection loop as you're not modifying your `$_COOKIE` value, so if it's set to *step_2* you will be constantly entering this if condition. Piror to issuing the header. Why not modify `$_COOKIE['step'] = 'step_3'`

Comment: @Brad I will, after I've got this working. I cant stop if something is not working the way it should. My personality.

Comment: FYI: Location should be an absolute URI

Comment: @DarylGill I was setting the cookie value, but I forgot to add it to my question. I just edited my question and added the value of the cookie.

Comment: @user3723069 Check my answer. Even when setting the cookie, you are keeping the same data, so will constantly hit into the same condition

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere are you actually setting your cookie value, so it won't change.  That's why you have an infinite loop.

`$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` have nothing to do with each other.  It looks like you want:

```
if ($_GET['step'] === 'your_details')`
```

...which would be better than using a cookie anyway.

Comment: I was setting the cookie value, but I forgot to add it to my question. I just edited my question and added the value of the cookie.

Comment: @user3723069 You're setting that cookie value to be the same thing over and over again

Comment: The reason why I'm setting the cookie is so that the user gets redirected to the step where they left the website - IF the cookie has been set. When the user hits the 'Next step' (which is step 3) the cookie value should change into step_3.

Comment: @user3723069 Well, a cookie isn't a good way of doing that.  Cookies are never guaranteed to last.  You should check the status of the data that the user sent in and then redirect them to the right step.  The step should be determined in the URL (so that each step has a distinct URL, if possible).

Comment: But wouldnt the redirect still be the same in this case, as it checks the users data and redirects him/her to the correct step? It would get in an infinite loop.

Comment: Your infinite redirect occurs because you aren't checking the right variables.  This is a trivial problem.  Once you have solved that, I'm saying that it's better for different pages to effectively have different URLs, for caching, crawling, bookmarking, etc.  By adding that query string with the step, you have different URLs for different pages... one for each step.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to constantly enter your `if` condition as there is no other manipulations going on to your cookie data.

if your cookie is set to "step_2" you will enter the loop. No changes are in place, so on the refresh to the page. You will re-enter the step_2 condition and be into a redirect.

I'm also assuming that you understand that your `$_GET` & `$_COOKIE` requests are completely different. If not, see @Brads answer

---

A solution to stop this infinite loop would be:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['step'])) {
    if ($_COOKIE['step'] == 'step_2') {
        $cookie_not_set = false;
        $cookie_step_two = true;
        $_COOKIE['step'] = 'step_3';
        header('Location: ?step=your_details');
        exit();
    }
```

But also take note, your true/false validations/changes are local changes and will not be absolute on page refresh

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is the redirect is not changing your cookie, so you need to look at the GET var you a re passing if the cookie is set to step_2 thus;

```
$cookie_not_set = true;
$cookie_step_two = false;

if (isset($_COOKIE['step'])) {
    if ($_COOKIE['step'] == 'step_2') {
       if( !empty($_GET['step']) && $_GET['step'] == 'your_details' )
       {
          ... you have redirected and now can continue ...
       }
       else
       {
         // redirect and set the get var to signal to this script.

          $cookie_not_set = false;
          $cookie_step_two = true;
          header('Location: ?step=your_details');
          exit();
        }
    }
} else {
    $cookie_not_set = true;
}
```